# Symbols instead of text Excel 2016

Tags: excel, text, formatting, symbols

I'm sure this kind of answer is already answered somewhere, but when I search I can't get a relevant result to my problem.

[image]

[image]

In text editor everything looks ok, but when I open this file with Excel I got symbols instead of letters.
What can be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a new excel file, go to Data--> Get External Data --> From Text and follow prompts. Worked for me just now.
[image]